# Showing a blocked UIAlertView in ViewDidAppear Method on iOS 7 with Xamarin.iOS does not work

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios7

if I try to show a blocked AlertView in the ViewDidAppear Method on iOS 7, I won´t be able to dismiss the AlertView.
No touch events will reach the AlertView. The Button of the View will be highlighted, but nothing happen.
If I run the same code on iOS < 7, it will work fine.

Here is the example code:

```cs
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        var alert = new UIAlertView("Title", "Message", null, "OK");
        alert.Dismissed += (sender, args) => result = true;
        alert.Show();

        while (!result)
            NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil(NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(0.1));
    }
```

I am using Xamarin.iOS Version 6.4.3.0 with Apple SDK 6.1.
I have the same problems with alpha of Xamarin.iOS 6.9.6.0 and Apple SDK 7.0.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

Thanks for help.

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA, and you don't have rights to discuss it in the public.

Comment: iOS7 is released today. An answer would be much appreciated, since I have the same problem ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not good idea to use `NSRunLoop` to block UI execution, but certainly there is a better way of doing it.

You can make use async/await pattern to wait for user to press the `UIAlertView` button. Here's the sample that you can use: https://gist.github.com/prashantvc/6725882

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Apple developer forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/887792), iOS 7 has a bug where the UIAlertView delegate will never be called once the RunLoop is started.  According to one person, it may still work on the iPad.  You can subscribe to email updates for that forum thread in case a fix or workaround is found.

Comment: Nicely spotted, I hope there will be a fix in  an upcoming iOS release. The iOS6 Cookbook by Erica Sadun has a receipe about implementing the ModalAlertDelegate: https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Cookbook/blob/master/C03%20Alerts/02%20-%20Modal/ModalAlertDelegate.m

This recipe does not work any more in iOS7, poor devs who applied the recipe in their apps (like I did).

Comment: Yeah, lots of people did the same thing using Monotouch / Xamarin based on this C# example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248244/iphone-uialertview-modal/4807697#4807697

Answer (score -1):

You should add

```
alert.Clicked += AlertViewClick;
```

and do stuff in

```
private void AlertViewClick (object sender, UIButtonEventArgs ea)
{
   //Stuff Here
}
```

and remove

```
 while (!result)
            NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil(NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(0.1));
```