# "If" statement quandary (turned out to be a UIAlertView quandary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I've been wrestling with this code for over a day, so am finally asking for help.

My problem, I believe, lies within one of these two methods, whose purpose is to detect conditions that require an alert to be displayed. The first method, activated by the "Done" button, looks for duplicate user selections from a `UITableview`:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

    if ([self.firstActivityLabel.text isEqualToString: @"1st"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity selected"
                                                        message:@"Please select an activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else if ([self.secondActivityLabel.text isEqualToString: @"2nd"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Need two activities for graph"
                                                        message:@"Please select another activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    if (self.currentSpec.fromDate)
    {
        // Assign activityOfInterest and benchmarkActivity
        // fromDate and toDate already assigned in timeFrameSelector if a time frame has been selected

        self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest = self.firstActivityLabel.text;
        self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity = self.secondActivityLabel.text;

    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No time frame selected"
                                                        message:@"Please select a time frame or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [self checkForInstances];

    // Sends to delegate AFTER all other decisions have been made and handled
    [self.delegate AvsAViewControllerIsDone:self.currentSpec];

    // Set timeFrameButton index so nothing is highlighted
    self.timeFrameButton.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
}
```

If these conditionals resolve correctly in each case, the second method comes into play, checking to be sure that instances of the selected items are present in the persistent store and alerting for various conditions:

```
-(void) checkForInstances
{
    NSPredicate *aOiCountFinderPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest];
    int aOiCount = [TimedActivity MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:aOiCountFinderPredicate];

    NSPredicate *bmaCountFinderPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity];
    int bmaCount = [TimedActivity MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:bmaCountFinderPredicate];

    // Alerts if no instances of selected item

    NSString *firstAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of %@",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest];
    NSString *secondAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of %@",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity];
    NSString *thirdAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of either selected criteria"];


    if (aOiCount == 0 && bmaCount > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:firstAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [self.myTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }

    else if (bmaCount == 0 && aOiCount > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:secondAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [self.myTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [alert show];
    }

    else if (aOiCount == 0 && bmaCount == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:thirdAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison or timeframe" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [self.myTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    NSLog(@"Number of instances of %@ is %d",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest,aOiCount);
    NSLog(@"Number of instances of %@ is %d",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity,bmaCount);

}
```

Things seem to work fine until we get to the second method. It correctly throws the prescribed alert, but not until after control goes back to the first method, then to a delegate method (`[self.delegate AvsAViewControllerIsDone:self.currentSpec];`) I.e., the delegate method fires before the alert appears. But of course, the alert is intended to stop things so that the user can rethink and correct his selections before it gets to that method.

I'd sure appreciate someone pointing out my mistake. I hope it's not something really stupid, but I wouldn't count on it.

Thanks for looking!

**Update:**

**Following the suggestion of @giorasch, I modified my code like this:**

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{


    if (self.currentSpec.fromDate)
    {
        // Assign activityOfInterest and benchmarkActivity
        // fromDate and toDate already assigned in timeFrameSelector if a time frame has been selected

        self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest = self.firstActivityLabel.text;
        self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity = self.secondActivityLabel.text;

    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No time frame selected"
                                                        message:@"Please select a time frame or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [self checkForInstances];

}


-(void) checkForInstances
{
    NSPredicate *aOiCountFinderPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest];
    int aOiCount = [TimedActivity MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:aOiCountFinderPredicate];

    NSPredicate *bmaCountFinderPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity];
    int bmaCount = [TimedActivity MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:bmaCountFinderPredicate];

    // Alerts if no instances of selected item

    NSString *firstAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of %@",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest];
    NSString *secondAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of %@",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity];
    NSString *thirdAlertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No instances of either selected criteria"];


    if (aOiCount == 0 && bmaCount > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:firstAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison or timeframe" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Clear" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert setTag:1];
//        checksPositiveForInstances = NO;
//        [self alertView:alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:0];
        [alert show];
    }

    else if (bmaCount == 0 && aOiCount > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:secondAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison or timeframe" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Clear" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert setTag:2];
//        checksPositiveForInstances = NO;
//        [self alertView:alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:0];
        [alert show];

    }

    else if (aOiCount == 0 && bmaCount == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:thirdAlertstr message:@"Please clear and select a different comparison or timeframe" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Clear" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert setTag:3];
//        checksPositiveForInstances = NO;
//        [self alertView:alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:0];
        [alert show];
    }

    else // Instances present in both registers, no alert, sends to delegate for processing
    {
        [self.delegate AvsAViewControllerIsDone:self.currentSpec];
    }

    NSLog(@"Number of instances of %@ is %d",self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest,aOiCount);
    NSLog(@"Number of instances of %@ is %d",self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity,bmaCount);

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self clearEverything]; // Responds to Clear button (cancelButton) on alert
    }

}


-(void) clearEverything
{
    UIButton *clearButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:102];

    //    UIButton *selectButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
    [self.mainSelectLabel setText:@"Select first activity"];
    [self.timeFrameButton setHidden:YES];
    [self.timeFrameLabel setHidden:YES];

    // Set timeFrameButton index so nothing is highlighted
    self.timeFrameButton.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;

    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [self.myTableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            UITableViewCell * cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [self.myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath animated:NO];
        }
    }
    self.lastIndexPath = nil;
    self.firstActivityLabel.text = @"1st";
    self.secondActivityLabel.text = @"2nd";
    [self.myTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    clearButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    doneButton.enabled = NO;


}
```

It all works properly now, although to be honest, it's not entirely clear to me that the delegate is necessary in this particular case. OTOH, I tried removing it, and control "dropped through" the alert to succeeding code. I'll need to do some further study on this, but I greatly appreciate the guidance!

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to use the alertview delegate in order to execute code depending on the user selection in the alertview window. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4248387/986169

Comment: I was vaguely aware of the UIAlertViewDelegate, but have been using alerts liberally throughout my app without using the delegate. This is the first problem I've encountered (that I know of). I'll need some time to look into this and change code accordingly. Many thanks for the quick response, and I'll come back here with an update once I've implemented your suggestion!

Comment: Please see update above. If you'd like to put your response into an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your entire code yet, I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

if ([self.firstActivityLabel.text isEqualToString: @"1st"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity selected"
                                                    message:@"Please select an activity or Cancel"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

else if ([self.secondActivityLabel.text isEqualToString: @"2nd"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Need two activities for graph"
                                                    message:@"Please select another activity or Cancel"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else{

    if (!self.currentSpec.fromDate)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No time frame selected"
                                                        message:@"Please select a time frame or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        // Assign activityOfInterest and benchmarkActivity
        // fromDate and toDate already assigned in timeFrameSelector if a time frame has been selected
        self.currentSpec.activityOfInterest = self.firstActivityLabel.text;
        self.currentSpec.benchmarkActivity = self.secondActivityLabel.text;

        [self checkForInstances];
        // Sends to delegate AFTER all other decisions have been made and handled
        [self.delegate AvsAViewControllerIsDone:self.currentSpec];
        // Set timeFrameButton index so nothing is highlighted
        self.timeFrameButton.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
    }
}
}
```