# Desperately need Xamarin.IOS modal MessageBox like popup

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

Coding in Xamarin IOS. I have a drop down list type popup, where, if The end user types in a new value, I want to ask a yes/no question: Do You want to add a new row?

The control is inside a UIStackView, which is inside a container UIView, which is in turn inside another which is presented via segue. Xamarin demanded a UIPopoverController, which I implemented. Here is The code I have so far:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace PTPED_Engine
{

    public enum MessagePopupType
    {
        YesNo = 1,
        OKCancel = 2,
        OKOnly = 3
    }

    public enum PopupResultType
    {
        OK = 1,
        Cancel = 2,
        Yes = 3,
        No = 4
    }

    public static class AlertPopups
    {
        static NSObject nsObject;

        public static void Initialize(NSObject nsObject)
        {
            AlertPopups.nsObject = nsObject;
        }
        public static Task<PopupResultType> AskUser(UIViewController parent, UIView V, string strTitle, string strMsg, MessagePopupType mpt)
        {
            using (UIPopoverController pc = new UIPopoverController(parent))
            {
               // pc.ContentViewController
                // method to show an OK/Cancel dialog box and return true for OK, or false for cancel
                var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<PopupResultType>();

                var alert = UIAlertController.Create(strTitle, strMsg, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
                // set up button event handlers
                if (mpt == MessagePopupType.OKCancel)
                {
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, a => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(PopupResultType.OK)));
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, a => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(PopupResultType.Cancel)));
                }
                if (mpt == MessagePopupType.YesNo)
                {
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Yes", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, a => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(PopupResultType.Yes)));
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("No", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, a => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(PopupResultType.No)));
                }
                if (mpt == MessagePopupType.OKOnly)
                {
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, a => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(PopupResultType.OK)));
                }
                // show it
                nsObject.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    pc.PresentFromRect(V.Bounds, V, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
                });

                return taskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I invoke it as follows:

```
LookupCombo.Completed += async (object sender, CompletedEventArgs e) =>
{
    C1AutoComplete AC = (C1AutoComplete)sender;
    if (AC.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        string sColName = AC.AccessibilityIdentifier.Trim();
        var ValuesVC = (List<Lookupcombo_Entry>)AC.ItemsSource;
        var IsThisAHit = from Lookupcombo_Entry in ValuesVC
                         where Lookupcombo_Entry.sDispVal.ToUpper().Trim() == e.value.ToUpper().Trim()
                         select Lookupcombo_Entry.sMapVal;
        if (!IsThisAHit.Any())
        {
            string sTitle = "";
            string sFull = _RM.GetString(sColName);
            if (sFull == null) { sFull = "???-" + sColName.Trim(); }
            sTitle = " Add New " + sFull.Trim() + "?";
            string sPPrompt = "Do you want to add a new " + sFull.Trim() + " named " + AC.Text.Trim() + " to the Database?";
            var popupResult = await AlertPopups.AskUser(CurrentViewController(), V, sTitle, sPPrompt, MessagePopupType.YesNo);
          }
    }
};
```

CurrentViewController is defined like this:

```
    private UIViewController CurrentViewController()
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }
        return vc;
    }
```

This does nothing. It hangs The user interface.

This should be built in, but it is only built in in Xamarin.Forms, which I do not want to use.

I have no problem in doing this stuff with an await, but this is simply not working. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything linking your alert to the popover

Comment: You can use the UserDialogs library https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: I added this before The invoke:

 pc.ContentViewController = alert;

no effect.

Comment: This is a very clever approach!   I had never thought of using await in this way to get a modal dialog going on.   That said, you say "simply not working" what part does not work?   The UI is never presented, or it never goes away?   I offered a few years ago an ugly alternative in stackoverflow that pumped the event queue, not a nice thing to do, I do like your approach better.

Comment: pnavk please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. The Acr dialogs is elegant and beautiful and worked perfectly the first time.  Thanks!!

Comment: miguel, nothing was ever presented.  I switched to acr dialogs and it worked well.  I will post up an answer with the code.

Comment: @JohnTamburo Added it as an answer. For your original approach, I think the problem was that you return on the task from your using block instead of awaiting it. This causes the popover to be disposed before it’s even displayed. If you change the end of your AskUser method to await taskCompletionSource.Task; that might be the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the ACR UserDialogs library:
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I provided a few years ago, I think it is an ugly hack, compared to your elegant approach.   You did not say what part does not work exactly, that might help spot the problem.

Here is my solution from a few years back:

[iphone UIAlertView Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248244/iphone-uialertview-modal/4807697#4807697)